# My android application stop suddenly when I try to access on element whith setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have made a little menu, and I am trying to access one intent if I click on one element. Then suddenly stops. What am I doing wrong? (The array is already populated on a XML values)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            String selection = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

            if (selection=="Extras"){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Novedades.class);
                startActivity(i);}



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Post logcat error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the mistake.

I forgot to include the intent on Manifest.xml

Thank everybody for your time and your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Never in java compare strings like this

```
if (selection == "Extras"){
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Novedades.class);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Use `selection.equals("Extras");`

But I am pretty certain your problems is in here

```
String selection = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your `selection` variable is null and could be the reason why
your application is crashing and use the `equals` function instead of  `"=="`.

```
if (selection != null && selection.equals("Extras")
{
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Novedades.class);
  startActivity(i);
}
```